# Register Variable Address

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Address of register variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256246/address-of-register-variable)

I know that getting address of register variable is not allowed in c . But why this code is getting compiled in c++ and not in c.

```
int main()
{
    register int a;
    printf("%u\n",&a);
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, MSVC and GCC will allow it. But Clang will reject it.

Comment: see this question : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256246/address-of-register-variable

Comment: It is compiled because you compiled it. I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking why it compiles as C++ with no errors?

Comment: yes jalf i want to know ehy it complies in c++ without errors

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256246/address-of-register-variable) is your answer.

Comment: `register` is only a hint to the compiler - it's pretty much obsolete these days and is typically ignored - if you take the address of a register variable then it will obviously not be kept in a register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword `register` is only a hint to the compiler. In fact, most compilers today ignore it as they contain advanced code to pick the best register variable candidates anyway.

Whenever you take the address of a variable, it is typically placed on the stack, despite the fact that you have used the `register` keyword.