# Pointer to register variables

Tags: c++, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Address of register variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256246/address-of-register-variable)

```
register int yy = 6;
int * myptr = &yy;
cout<<myptr<<" "<<&yy<<" "<<*myptr<<" "<<yy<<endl;
```

Deitel and Deitel third edition C++ how to program : page # 307 last line says - address operator can not be applied to variables declared with the storage class register. How come the above code prints :
0x28ff24 0x28ff24 6 6

Am I missing something about pointer to variables with register storage class?

Comment: Note that `register` is an anachronism. Compilers these days can do a far better job of deciding what to put in registers than your or I can. And since the compiler is free to ignore it, it does. Don't bother trying to figure out how to use it.

Comment: @raymond ..yes i agree, flagged this ! thanks for the link though

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is ignoring your `register` request because your code takes the address of `yy`.

Answer (score 2):

Your book is out of date.

In modern C++, the use of the `register` keyword is deprecated, and has no effect on the declaration (beyond perhaps acting as a hint to the compiler that the variable might be heavily used). It does not prevent you from taking the address of the variable.

C does have that restriction; and presumably older version of C++ also did, but I don't have any historical documents available to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Address of register variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256246/address-of-register-variable)

Separately, here is IBMs documentation on the matter for one of their compilers:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fregdef.htm