# What kind of variable in C can not be addressed?

Tags: c, memory-management, var

Usually a variable `'abc'` may be addressed as `'&abc'`.

What kind of variable in c can not be addressed? Why?

Comment: This a quiz?....

Answer (score 4):

This is addressed<sup>*</sup> by section 6.5.3.2 of the C99 standard (emphasis mine):

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a
>   `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates **an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the `register` storage-class specifier**.

---

<sub>* LOL</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the register variables in C can not be addressed can be found here:

[Address of register variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256246/address-of-register-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Register variable can not be accesses by this way. A register does not have an address.    Therefore, you cannot apply the address operator (&) to a register variable.