# Address of a variable stored in a register

Tags: c

If somewhere in my code, I use the address of a variable (pass it to some other function, for example), the compiler will automatically choose to store it in memory? (as opposed to the possibility of storing it in a register).

Otherwise, what happens if I ask for the address of a variable like that (stored as register)? I know we can't take the address of variables explicitly set to register (`register int c`).

*EDIT*:

For example, if i do something like

```
int c = 1;
print("Address of c: %p", &c);
```

Then this variable couldn't be stored in a register, could it? The compiler would automatically set it as stored in memory? Otherwise (if it is just stored in a register), what would be the address shown in the screen?

Comment: It's unclear to me what it is that you're asking. If you're talking about function arguments, then they're all handled via the stack.

Comment: some calling conventions use the stack others use registers, or a combination of both.  they are not all handled by the stack, unless you are talking about a specific calling convention on a specific architecture with a specific compiler.

Comment: I mean using the address of the variable in a general sense. For example, i could just print the address to the screen.

Comment: Add 'volatile' to the mix as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, the C Standard prohibits taking the address of a variable that is declared `register`, just as it does for bit fields in `struct`s.

For non-register ("auto") variables, the short answer is yes.  The simplest strategy of an optimizer is to immediately spill variables whose addresses are taken.

"Spill" is just a term from the literature of register allocation meaning "decide to place in memory rather than a register."

A sophisticated optimizer can do an *alias analysis* and still hold a value in a register, even though its address has been taken.  This is possible wherever it can be proven that the resulting pointer can't possibly be used to change the value.

Another relevant optimization is *live range splitting*. This allows a variable to be stored in a register for part of the range of instructions where it's holding a useful value (its "live range") and to be spilled in other parts.  In this case the spilled parts would correspond to places where the pointer *might* be used to change the variable's value.  For example:

```
x = 3;
... lots of computations involving x
if T {
  // SPILL HERE, so store register holding x to memory
  int *p = &x;
  ... lots of computations, perhaps using p to change x
  *p = 2;
  // DONE SPILL HERE, so reload register
  ... more code here not using p to change x.
}
else {
  ... lots of computations involving x.
}
```

An aggressive optimizer of this code might allocate a stack position for x, but load it into a register at the top of the code, maintaining it there except for the region marked as a SPILL.  This region would be surrounded by a store of the register to memory and a matching register load.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really get the first second sentence in first paragraph. The optimizer (compiler) spills those variables?

Comment: "Spill" simply means that the register allocator decides to put a variable in memory rather than a register. Spills can occur for many reasons.  Perhaps the most common is that there are more variables than registers, so some variables must "spill" out of the available register pool.

Answer (score 3):

By taking its address, you force the compiler to put the variable in memory and not to to optimize it into a register.

This answer has some good info: [Address of register variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256246/address-of-register-variable)

Comment: This is not accurate. I compiled `int foo(int x) { int y = x, *z = &y; return *z * *z; }` with Apple clang version 4.0 using `cc -O3 -std=c99 -S` and examined the generated assembly code. At no point did it put `x` or `y` in memory. The compiler is only compelled to put the value in memory if it is unable to determine that the required “observable” behavior cannot be provided otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has to be very careful with optimizing pointers, because anyone can change them behind the scenes.  This is why optimizing keywords like `restrict` exist (telling the compiler that there are no other copies of the pointer anywhere).  So generally you won't have the situation you describe.