# About Use Of Storage Classes in C

Tags: c

The following code displays an error if the Storage Class of the parameters of the function `int *check(register int,register int);` declared as some other Storage Class.

I compiled this code on *Code::Blocks 10.05 IDE* with *GNU GCC Compiler*. What is the reason behind the error? Is it a compiler specific error or a general one?
The code section  begins from here:

```
int *check(register int, register int);

int main()
{
  int *c;
  c = check(10, 20);
  printf("%d\n", c);
  return 0;
}

int *check(register int i,register int j)
{
  int *p = i;
  int *q = j;
  if(i >= 45)
    return (p);
  else
    return (q);
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? What is this code supposed to do? Why are you using `register` declarations?

Comment: Your code is compiled in GCC 4.7.3 on Ubuntu 13.04 with some warnings, and outputs `20`, as expected.

Comment: @Earth Engine,@interjay, Please look into the question again... it specifies that the code displays error in case of declaring the storage class of the parameters as static,or auto or extern on the previously mentioned compiler version...not with the register storage class.

Comment: Is that error appear in your IDE only?

Comment: I have tried it with Code::Block Nov 11 2012 on Windows 8, but I cannot see your error. It compiles and go with result `20`.

Comment: I have tried it in Code::Block SVN 8549 on Windows 8, but there is still no errors and results in `20`. Can you attach your project settings?

Comment: I can only see one red sign beside your `printf` function call, which indicates you should use `"%p\n` rather than `"%d\n"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *check(register int i,register int j)
{
int *p=i;
int *q=j;
if(i >= 45)
return (p);
else
return (q);
}
```

While `register` storage class specifier is allowed on parameter declaration, parameters `i` and `j` have `int` type while `p` and `q` are of type `int *`. This makes the declaration of `p` and `q` invalid.

You cannot just change this to:

```
int *p=&i;
int *q=&j;
```

as the `&` operator does not allow you to have an operand of `register` storage class.

You cannot also also change the parameter declaration from `register int i`  and `register int j` to `int i` and `int j` and then return the address of `i` and `j` object as their lifetime ends at the exit of the function.

In your case you should just not use pointers: use `int` parameters and an `int` return value.

Comment: :-please read the question thoroughly.This code does not generate error but any storage class declaration in place of Register(Like auto,static or extern ) generates error and this fact has been mentioned in the question precisely.Thank you for your efforts...a closer look into the question is expected.

Comment: @ChandanKumar I read you program thoroughly, I suggest you to read my answer thoroughly. The fact that your compiler accepts your program does not mean is not an erroneous program. First a compiler can refuse your program because of the typing error between `int *` and `int`, second it invokes undefined behavior because you are attempting to access an object whose lifetime is over.

Comment: can there be any explanation why this program is not taking any other keyword like static or auto in place of register here?

Comment: @ChandanKumar C says in C99, 6.7.5.3p2 *"The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is register."*

Comment: That is what i wanted to know through this code... Thank you very much.It serves my purpose.

Answer (score 5):

```
int *check(register int i,register int j)
{   
    int *p=i;
    int *q=j;
```

Type mismatch of `p` `q` and `i` `j`. Perhaps what you want is :

```
int *check(int i, int j)
{   
    int *p=&i;
    int *q=&j;
```

Correction: Note that `register` cannot be used with `&`. Besides, the keyword `register` has little usage because the compiler usually ignores it and does the optimization itself.

Comment: Does storage specifier change type? Interesting. Why is that?

Comment: @sasha.sochka No. But a pointer is distinct from what it points to.

Comment: This would return a pointer to a local variable. And I believe you can't take the address of a `register` variable.

Comment: @interjay Thanks for that, I didn't notice it, fixed.

Comment: I believe he want to check the first parameter is a valid pointer, and if so return the pointer value, otherwise return the second as a pointer value.

Answer (score 2):

**First** type mismatch:

```
int *p=i;
int *q=j;
```

**Second** side note `&` not applied/valid  on register variables.

From: [address of register variable in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559774/address-of-register-variable-in-c-and-c)

In C, you cannot take the address of a variable with `register` storage. Cf. C11 6.7.1/6:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier `register`
>   suggests that access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such
>   suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.

**third:** Returning address of local object is Undefined behavior (and parameters of functions counts in local variables). Don't return address of that there life is till function returns.

**Suggestion:**

To return address, you need to do dynamic allocation and return address of that. for example:

```
int *check(int i,int j){
    int *p= malloc(sizeof (int));
    int *q= malloc(sizeof (int));
    *p = i;
    *q = j; 
    if(i >= 45){
      free(q);
      return (p);
    }
    else{
      free(p);
      return (q);
   }
}
```

Note returned  address is not of `i`, `j`, but its address of dynamically allocated memory. Don't forget to call `free(a)` in `main()`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes. It has to be done on the `main` function.

Comment: @EarthEngine I pointed out and corrected. Not only main because we are not returning  address of both one has to free in function itself. Thanks! Earch

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan The point is his strange code is compiled! see my answer or my comment on his post.

Comment: @EarthEngine are you here!

Answer (score 1):

In my machine with GCC 4.7.3 on Ubuntu 13.04, the output is

```
$gcc test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
test.c:7:3: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]
test.c: In function ‘check’:
test.c:13:12: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
test.c:14:12: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
$./a.out
20
```

It accepts the program with a lot of warnings. And there is not a single word says "storage class". so I wonder what version of GCC you are using?

The first two warnings can be fixed by `#include <stdio.h>` and change `%d` in the printf function call to `%p`. Let's ignore those for now and focus on the rest two. Depends on what you want to do, you can have different options to eliminate them.

If you want to return the address of `i` or `j` as a stack based variable (which is unusual because it is invalid after return to the caller), you can do

```
int *check( int i, int j)
{   
    int *p = &i;
    int *q = &j;
    ...
```

You cannot obtain the address of a register variable, so you have to remove them. In this case, with your `main` function your program will print something like `0x7fffc83021f8` in my machine. That is the pointer value to the variable `j`, although it is not valid at the time we prints it, as long as you do not attempt to dereference it everything is OK.

If this is not what you want, you probably want to force the integer `i` or `j` to represent a pointer, then you need to do

```
 int *check(register int i,register int j)
 {
    int *p=(int *)i;
    int *q=(int *)j;
    if(i >= 45)
        return (p);
    else
        return (q);
 }
```

Note in this case the use of register keyword is OK although it may have very limited effect. Also this would still warn you when you compile the code in some machine (especially 64 bit GCC).

Although strange, but this code have some sense: usually an integer that too close to zero is not a valid pointer.

So what this code does is: it returns `i`'s value as a pointer if it's a valid pointer(value  greater than 45), or return `j`s value. The result in this case is `0x14` (remember we need to replace `%d` to `%p`, so the output is in hexadecimal).

*EDIT*

After look at your `main` function I believe what is wanted here would be

```
 int check(register int i,register int j)
 {
    int p=i;
    int q=j;
    if(i >= 45)
        return (p);
    else
        return (q);
 }
```

But anyway this code can be simplified as

```
 int check(register int i,register int j)
 {
    if(i >= 45)
        return i;
    else
        return j;
 }
```

or even

```
 int check(register int i,register int j)
 {
    return i>=45 ? i : j;
 }
```

in these cases the `main` function should be

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    c = check(10, 20);
    printf("%d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Note since the data type of `c` is now `int` so the `%p` for `printf` is restored back to `%d`. The output is the same of the original code: `20`.

Comment: `int *p=(int *)i;` I dislike because `sizeof(address)` may not equals to `sizeof(int)` on some machine

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Of cause. but I think the use of `register` means you want to control the code at a very low level. so machine specific code is acceptable. Also, use 45 to detect pointer validation IS machine-specific.

Comment: @ Grijesh Chauhan,@Earth Engine and @interjay :- Before flagging a question as not useful,please read the question thoroughly.This code does not generate error but any storage class declaration in place of Register(Like auto,static or extern ) generates error and this fact has been mentioned in the question precisely.Thank you for your efforts...a closer look into the question is expected.

Answer (score 0):

OK now I see what you are asking.

If you have a function prototype declaration like this:

```
int *check(register int, register int);
```

As soon as the compiler sees this, it can enforce a rule that no code will attempt to obtain the address of the parameters. It is up to the compiler to consider a consistent way to generate code for function calls through out the program based on this fact. This may or may not be the same as

```
int *check(int, int);
```

Which performs the default treatment of parameters (but again the compiler will ensure it is consistent through out the program).

But consider the following:

```
int *check(auto int, auto int);
```

The compiler do not know weather the address of the parameter is going to be used or not unless it sees the actual implementation. So it cannot assume anything. The programmer obviously want some optimization, but the compiler do not have any further information to do so.

So it does not make sense to specify a parameter to be `auto`.

What if use `auto` for parameters of function definition? Again this makes little sense. The compiler can have a strategy that if there is no attempt to obtain the parameter address then treat it as `register` other use stack for it. But for parameters that do not use `auto` the rule would be the same. So it does not gives the compiler any further information.

Other storage classes are even makes no sense for parameters in function definition. It is not possible to pass a parameter through static data area or the heap (you can only pass pointers - which actually in the stack or registers).