# The function va_start(va_list ap,parmN) defined in stdarg.h, Why the identifier parmN must not be declared with register storage class?

Tags: c

The function va_start() which is defined in header file stdarg.h has two argument va_list ap and parmN here parmN is the identifier naming the rightmost parameter in the variable parameter list in the function definition (the one just before the , ... ). Here i donot understand that why it is said that it must not be declared with register storage class.

Comment: It is related to the fact that [you cannot take an address of register variable in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559774/address-of-register-variable-in-c-and-c)

Comment: It is quite likely also connected to the ABI parameter passing via registers.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: @EugeneSh. does the argument parmN is passed by reference in va_start?

Comment: If you look at some implementations of `va_start` you will notice the `&argN` notation.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, [`va_start` is a **macro**, not a *function*](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.16.1p1).

> The `va_start` and `va_arg` macros described in this subclause shall be implemented as macros, not functions.

Now, with that out of the way, the [C99 rationale](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) answers your question:

> The restrictions on the declaration of the `parmN` parameter follow from the intent to allow this kind of implementation, as applying the `&` operator to a parameter name might not produce the intended result if the parameter’s declaration did not meet these restrictions.

In summary, the standards committee wanted to give C standard libraries the freedom to implement variadic arguments using the `&` operator, and if `parmN` were to have `register` storage duration then the standard library might cause undefined behaviour due to a violation of [section 6.5.3.2, paragraph 1](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p1):

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the `register` storage-class specifier.

Comment: It's not just undefined behavior. It's a constraint violation, requiring a compile-time diagnostic.