# Can I change the address of the pointer variable in C language?

Tags: c, pointers, swap

For example, if there is a pointer variable `int *a`, `int *b` and each address value is `1000`, `2000`, can the address value of the pointer variable be swapped as if it were swapping the value of the common variable?

Note,  I mean the address of the *pointer*. Not the *value* it contains.

As far as I know, the address value of the pointer variable is fixed and cannot be changed, is that right?

Comment: It is easy enough to try.

Comment: stark Are you saying that we can exchange the value of &a and &b?

Comment: @honghoker I don't get your question. Please [edit] and instead of describing what pointer contains which value show an example. BTW you can use translate.google.com, it works really well even for chinese, japanese and other languages very different from english

Comment: I'm saying that in the time it took to write this question you could have written `{int *a, *b, *tmp; tmp = a; a=b; b=tmp;}` and tried it.

Comment: By the way, the word "variable" means "changeable".

Comment: You can change the address that a pointer variable contains simply by assigning to it.  You can't change the address of the variable itself, just as you can't change the address of any other variable.  In other words, if you have `int *a;`, you can assign to `a` to change the address it contains, but you can't assign to `&a`, which is the address of the variable itself.

Comment: A lot of people answered, but I think I asked the wrong question. I'm sorry, but my question is not about "change content of a pointer variable", but "change address of a pointer variable."

Comment: I answered both questions.  See the comment right above yours.  The answer is "no", you cannot change the address of a variable.  You may only change its contents.

Comment: I would argue that changing the address of a pointer is not just impossible. It's fundamentally impossible. The address is what defines a variable.

Comment: Note that a pointer variable, or any object, may not even have an address if declared with  `register`.

Answer (score 3):

From comments:

> A lot of people answered, but I think I asked the wrong question. I'm sorry, but my question is not about "change content of a pointer variable", but "change address of a pointer variable."

No, that's impossible for any variable. Not just pointers.

Comment: Oh Thank you and thank everyone for reading my stuffy post.

Answer (score 1):

*Can I change the address of the pointer variable in c language?*

While the answer to your question would be *yes* for [many other languages](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Address_of_a_variable#Set_the_Address), including C++, kind of:

> *"While C++ doesn't directly support putting a variable at a given address, the same effect can be achieved by creating a reference to
> that address:"*...

...the answer for `C` is No.  [*"A pointer has an address like other variables (which can't and needn't be changed)"*](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/108081-changing-address-pointer-question.html).  (quote from 4th response in link.)

For `C`, the address of all variables (with the exception of those declared as [register](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17559955/645128)) are assigned at the time of declaration as a memory location provided by the operating system, and are immutable for the remainder of their life, no matter the scope in which they were created.
So, while the address *pointed to* by a pointer variable can be changed, the *address of* the variable itself, cannot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to know if I can change the value of the address that is printed when printing &a and &b as a printf function.

Comment: ryyker Thank you for your effort, but what I want is not a change in pA, pB, but a change in &pA, &pB.

Comment: No problem, it was a confusing question anyhow 

Comment: @honghoker - I mis-interpreted your question, but have edited to correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```
void swapPointers(void **a, void **b) {
    void *t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

void someOtherFunc() {
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *y = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *x = 3;
    *y = 5;
    printf("x = %d y = %d\n", *x, *y);

    swapPointers(&x, &y);
    printf("x = %d y = %d\n", *x, *y);
}
```

Comment: In fact, you cannot change the *address of a pointer* but if the correct phrase is "can I swap the values of the pointers where they point to", then the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean swapping addresses stored in pointers because you can not swap addresses of pointers as declared variables themselves.

To swap two objects in a function you have to pass them by reference. Otherwise the function will deal with copies of the values of passed directly to it objects.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it.

Pointers are the same objects.

So you can write the swap function the following way

```
void swap_ptr( int **a, int **b )
{
    int *tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
int *a = /*...*/;
int *b = /*...*/;

//...

swap_ptr( &a, &b );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can swap the address the pointer points to.

```
int main()
{
     int x = 5, y = 10;
     int* p1 = &x;
     int* p2 = &y;
     printf("Address pointed by p1 is: %p\n", p1);
     printf("Address pointed by p2 is: %p\n", p2);
     //Here goes the swapping
     int* p3 = p1;
     p1 = p2;
     p2 = p3; 
     printf("\n--After swap--\n");
     printf("Address pointed by p1 is: %p\n", p1);
     printf("Address pointed by p2 is: %p\n", p2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can you just need to swap where each pointer point to.
declare a 3rd pointer then do the swap as follow.

```
//we have *a and *b

int *tmp;
tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can swap the address stored in two pointer using a temporary pointer variable. But if the pointer is declared as constant pointer for exapmle *const int *ptr1;* then it not possible because the address stored in ptr1 cannot be modified

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int a=10;
   int b=20;
   int *ptr1;
   int *ptr2;
   ptr1=&a;
   ptr2=&b;
   cout<<ptr1<<" "<<ptr2<<"\n";
   int *temp;
   temp=ptr1;
   ptr1=ptr2;
   ptr2=temp;
   cout<<ptr1<<" "<<ptr2;

   return 0;

   }
```

you can change the syntax to c because I thought that I was answering a question from c++ section