# C: Address on register or memory?

Tags: c, pointers, processor

I am a bit confused by the key word "register" in C.
It seems to tell the compiler that it should be stored in a register which means that some of my variables are stored in Registers and some in memory? If so, is there a way to find out whether my value is stored in a register or in Memory?

For example:

```
int *x =  (int*) 0x1234;
```

X does not seem to point on a register now, because such addresses are for memory.
But I have tried several times to find a different looking address (also using "register" key word). Even on the internet nobody seems to care.

So my main question: How does the address in a pointer look when it points on a register?

EDIT: I can't find an answer to my main question at the end of my question in the other question. My question is NOT about the key word "register", I just mentioned it.

Comment: I don't think the compilers these days pay attention to the `register` keyword.  Somebody correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: For `int *x =  (int*) 0x1234;` surely the address `0x1234` is a *memory* address, not a register, but the variable `x` itself has a location (which holds `0x1234`), and that could be a register or in memory.

Comment: The compiler ultimately decides where and how to store variables and intermediate values, but the strategy used depends on your optimization level. Highly optimized code makes extensive use of registers for performance reasons. If you want to know exactly how your code is compiled, look at the assembler output.

Comment: I think you're somewhat confused. First, the `register` keyword is not a command, it's a suggestion to the compiler: *Hey, if it's OK with you, I'd like you to use a register for this for speed*. The compiler is not required to take that suggestion if it thinks it has better ways to optimize the code. Second, there's no reason for you to really care whether it succeeded in being placed in a register or not, because there's nothing that changes in your code as a result. Third, a register is in the CPU itself; why do you think you can (or should) read it's address?

Comment: Thank you @lurker . Makes sense to me now.

Comment: You cannot point to a CPU register as they are not memory mapped.  If you are referring to _peripheral registers_ on the other hand; these _are_ memory mapped and have addresses in the address space, and the declaration would be just as you have it - except you do need the `volatile` type modifier.  The `register` keyword has nothing to do with _peripheral registers_.  Fix your question - it is remarkably unclear, and I would vote to re-open it, or more likely point to a better duplicate.

Comment: Also, if you ever take the address of a variable, the compiler is forced to ignore your "register" suggestion.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons `register` remains useful with select compilers to improve performance, yet many compilers for large processors do not benefit and may even hinder them.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Concerning "ever take the address of a variable, the compiler is forced to ignore your "register" suggestion" is contradicted by [C99 6.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1256273/2410359).  Perhaps you are thinking of another language?

Comment: It was a mistake to mark this C-only question as a duplicate of a question asking about a difference between C and C++, and one that (due to its age) addresses old standards.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons : GCC v8  details how `register` _may_ affect code generation. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/gcc/Hints-implementation.html#Hints-implementation  It only applies at optimisation level 0 (no optimisation), at higher levels it is ignored, because the optimiser will do better at figuring out what to put in a register than you will, and will account for the register set limitations of the specific target.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, chux is correct in that C99 6.7.1 states that it is an _error_ to attempt to take the address. So it would not ignore it; rather it would just not compile.  For example GCC yields `error: address of register variable 'x' requested`.  It will compile as C++ because C++ is required to ignore the `register` keyword in all circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the address in a pointer look when it points on a register?

Pointers are a concept of memory, registers do not have addresses. Every processor has a limited, fixed amount of registers (8 - 16 probably).

As others have mentioned, the `register` is not really useful anymore and even sometimes ignored by compilers.

To understand what registers really are, consider this example:

```
int a = k / 53;  // k is an int defined somewhere else...
int b = a * 9;
// a is not used after the above line
```

Now, we have not declared `a` with `register` but any reasonable compiler will still keep a in a register.

The reason for this is that to perform any operation the operands have to be in certain registers. The the result of the operation will then e.g. be stored in the register of the first operand.

In order to compute `a` from the above example, the compiler will write code to load `k` (which presumably is in memory) into a certain register (let's call it register A) and 53 into another. After the computation is done, register A will contain the result of the operation. Since we are going to multiple that result by nine in the next line anyway, we can just keep it were it is, load 9 into the other register and multiply. Storing the value into memory and then loading it back into a register would just waste a lot of time.

Note that declaring `a` with `volatile` would prevent optimizations like this and force the compiler to actually store and load `a`. (Although `volatile` does not make any sense with this example here at all, and is hardly ever useful if you do not, for instance, interface special kind of hardware.)

Answer (score 3):

The **storage class specifier** `register` was created on first release of **C** language to instruct compiler to use one of the processors registers to hold the variable having the scope to allow for faster access. At that time code writing required much attention from the programmer because the compilers were not so smart to detect errors or correct them leading to buggy code.

Anyway while growing-up the C standard got some tricks that made difficult to understand some details.

The storage class specifier `register` is one of those. So let's start looking at specs before to comment them.

From **ISO/IEC 9899:2011**, C11 standard:

> **§6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers**
>
> A declaration of an identifier for an object with
>   storage-class specifier register suggests that access to the object be
>   as fast as possible. The extent to which such suggestions are
>   effective is implementation-defined. (See note 119)

And the note 119:

> **NOTE**
>
> The implementation may treat any register declaration simply as an auto declaration. However, whether or not addressable
>   storage is actually used, the address of any part of an object
>   declared with storage-class specifier register cannot be computed,
>   either explicitly (by use of the unary `&` operator as discussed in
>   6.5.3.2) or implicitly (by converting an array name to a pointer as discussed in 6.3.2.1). Thus, the only operator that can be applied to
>   an array declared with storage-class specifier register is sizeof.

This means that the storage specifier `register` is a **suggestion** to the compiler to use processor registers or any other means to make the variable access as fast as possible, but the compiler can take a different decision. It can treat the declared variable as a standard `auto` variable.

In the last case it could be technically possible to obtain the storage address, but this is explicitly prohibited by the standard as explained in the note, but also enforced in the **constraints** of **§6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**:

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function
>   designator, the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that
>   designates an object that is not a bit-field and **is not declared with
>   the `register` storage-class specifier**.

Of course some **uncompliant compilers** may let you apply the operator.

Now going back to your very question:

1. > `int *x =  (int*) 0x1234;` X does not seem to point on a register now,
   >   because such addresses are for memory. But I have tried several times
   >   to find a different looking address (also using "register" key word).
   >   Even on the internet nobody seems to care.

**Your example is wrong**, you are declaring a pointer to an int and assigning an arbitrary address to it. This has nothing to do the `register` storage specifier.

Declare `register int *x =  (int*) 0x1234;` and then try to apply the `&` operator to `x` as in `int **pp = &x;` (note that we are declaring a pointer to a pointer to `int` that is what we get taking the address of a pointer to `int`).

You'll get an error on compliant compilers.

2. > So my main quesition: How does the address in a pointer look when it
   >   points on a register?

The answer is simple: **it doesn't resemble anything because it can't exist in standard C**.

Answer (score 0):

In modern compilers, an object you declare in C does not necessarily have a single location in which it exists. To optimize your program, the compiler may keep it in a register at some times, on the stack at others, or in a particular memory location at others. Normally, you do not need to know which.

When you take the address of the object and work with pointers, the compiler makes your program work as if the object did have a fixed address. Often this is done by putting the object in an assigned memory location, at least for the duration of time that you are using its address, but the compiler is allowed to achieve the end results of your program by other means.

If you declare an object with `register`, you are not supposed to, by the C standard, take its address. However, some compilers may permit this.

Comment: Note the added part of the question about not being about the `register` keyword, and my comment about _peripheral registers_. The question remains unclear, but it seems that this may not be an answer to the question @user84037 thinks he is asking.

Answer (score 0):

In most architectures you cannot point to a CPU register as they are not memory mapped. (8051 is one architecture I can think of where the core registers *are* memory mapped).

If you are referring to *peripheral registers* on the other hand; these *are* memory mapped and have addresses in the address space, and the declaration would be just as you have it - except you do need the volatile type modifier.

```
volatile int* x =  (volatile int*)0x1234 ;
```

The `register` keyword has nothing to do with memory mapped *peripheral registers*.