# Why register array names can be assigned to pointer variables without compiler error?

Tags: c, clang, c89, storage-class-specifier, register-keyword

I have a question about `register` keyword in C.

I found that `register` array name(e.g. `array`) can be assigned to pointer variable while `&array[0]` cannot be.

Can you explain why array name can be assigned to pointer? Or, if someone already explained it, please let me know links so that I can take a look to get the answer. Thank you.

**Here is what I tried:**

I read [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) which explains `register` keyword and it says:

> register arrays are not convertible to pointers.

Also, I read C89 draft which says:

> The implementation may treat any register declaration simply as an auto declaration. However, **whether or not addressable storage is actually used, the address of any part of an object declared with storage-class specifier register may not be computed**, either explicitly (by use of the unary & operator as discussed in 3.3.3.2) or **implicitly (by converting an array name to a pointer as discussed in 3.2.2.1).** Thus the only operator that can be applied to an array declared with storage-class specifier register is sizeof.

This looks like I can't assign register array name to pointer to get its address.

Moreover, to find the answer, I searched here and found this question: 
[Address of register variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256246/address-of-register-variable). There are good answers, however, still I couldn't find the answer what I wanted.

Here is the code which I tested. I compiled this code through **Clang** with flag `-std=c89`:

```cpp
register int array[10];
int* p;

p = array;     // Compiled without warning or error
p = &array[0]; // Compiled with error which I expected
```

I expected both `p = array;` and `p = &array[0];` caused compiled error, but only `p = &array[0];` made a compile error.

Comment: Why are you using `-std=c89`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is just my curiosity. I want to know old C even though I know that some of them are deprecated or removed, or there are better ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the Clang compiler. 
[GCC shows an error on both lines.](https://godbolt.org/z/HKm3v6)

In discussing the automatic conversion of “array of *type*” to “pointer to *type*”, C 2018 6.3.2.1 says:

> … If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Further, C 2018 footnote 124 says:

> … the address of any part of an object declared with storage-class specifier `register` cannot be computed, either explicitly (by use of the unary `&` operator as discussed in 6.5.3.2) or implicitly (by converting an array name to a pointer as discussed in 6.3.2.1)…

Obviously, `p = array;` converts `array` to a pointer, as discussed in 6.3.2.1, but this footnote (which is non-normative but tells us the intent in this case quite explicitly) says the value for that pointer cannot be computed.

Since the behavior is not defined by the C standard, a C implementation could define it as an extension. However, the inconsistent behavior between `array` and `&array[0]` suggests this is not a deliberate extension by Clang but is a mistake.